# Find nearest point relative to an object without using the distance formula in Java

Tags: java, math, coordinates, distance

If I have an object with properties of x an y, how can I tell which point in an array is the closest without using the distance formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get an accurate result without using *some* variant of the distance formula. But you *can* save a few cycles by not taking the square root after the fact; the comparison will remain valid.

> r = dx<sup>2</sup> + dy<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Can't you just add the x distance and the y distance?

Comment: No. A point with a dx of 1 and a dy of 1 has a distance of 1.414. A point with a dx of 1.5 and a dy of 0 has a distance of 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the exact distance, you could perhaps take the difference between the x and y coordinates of your source and destination points to provide you with some ordering.

```
//The following code does not return the closest point, 
//but it somewhat does what you need and complies with 
//your requirement to not use the distance formula
//it finds the sum of x and y displacements

Point destination=...  
Point nearestPoint= points.get(0);
for (Point p : points){
    closenessCoefficient= Math.abs(destination.x-p.x) + Math.abs(a.destination-p.y);
    nearestPoint=Math.Min(closenessCoefficient, nearestPoint);
}
return nearestPoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to find exactly the closest neighbour, there is no way around evaluating the distance formula, at least for a couple of points. As already pointed out, you can avoid evaluating the expensive sqrt for most of the time when simply comparing the distance-squared r^2 = x^2 + y^2.

However, if you have a big number of points spread out over a large range of distances, you can first use an approximation like the ones shown here http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml . Then you can calculate the real distance formula only for the points closest as given by the approximation. On architectures where also the multiplication is expensive, this can make a big difference. On modern x86/x86-64 architectures this should not matter much though.